# UCSR0B equivalent for ESP2866

Tags: serial, communication, uart

I'm trying to convert an Arduino Uno program for use with the ESP2866. I've converted most of the program successfully, but there are a few lines I can't seem to figure out. For example,

```
  UCSR0B = 0b10011101;
  UCSR0B = 0b10011100;
```

These lines result in the following error:

```
Compilation error: 'UCSR0B' was not declared in this scope
```

My understanding is that these lines modify parameters within one of the Uno's serial registers. Is it possible to do the equivalent action on the ESP? I have tried researching this but have found very little info online. I am using Arduino IDE v2.2.1. Thank you!

Comment: When porting software from one target to another, especially if it accesses hardware directly, **always** needs reading and understanding the documentation of both targets. Before you post a question here, you are supposed to do this homework, which you apparently did not.

Answer (score 1):

UCSR0B is the UART Control and Status Register on an ATMEGA328, the processor used on many Arduino models. This is extract from the ATMEGA328 datasheet shows what the bits do:

[image]

Setting it to 0b10011101 enables RXCIE, RXEN,TXEN, UCSZ2 and TXB, and setting to the 0b10011100 sets all of the bits except TXB. Setting UCSZ2 enables 9-bit mode, and setting or clearing TXB sets or clears the ninth bit for transmitted data.

Taking a quick look at the ESP8266 UART config, the UART supports a maximum of 8 bits, so if your app definitely requires 9 bits, you won't be able to do it on an ESP8266.

```
typedef enum {
    UART_DATA_5_BITS = 0x0,    /*!< word length: 5bits*/
    UART_DATA_6_BITS = 0x1,    /*!< word length: 6bits*/
    UART_DATA_7_BITS = 0x2,    /*!< word length: 7bits*/
    UART_DATA_8_BITS = 0x3,    /*!< word length: 8bits*/
} uart_word_length_t;
```